# how to load the data from local json file using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<!DOCTYPE html>


<html>
  <head>
      <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="people"></select>
  </body>

     <script type="text/JavaScript">
         $select = $('#people');
         //request the JSON data and parse into the select element
         $.ajax({
             type:'POST',
             url: './Person.JSON',
             dataType:'JSON',
             success:function(data){
                 //clear the current content of the select
                 $select.html('');
                 //iterate over the data and append a select option
                 $.each(data.person, function(key, val){
                     $select.append('<option id="' + val.id + '">' + val.name + '</option>');
                 })
             },
             error:function(){
                 //if there is an error append a 'none available' option
                 $select.html('<option id="-1">none available</option>');
             }
         });
  </script>
</html>
```

Hi the data from local json file cannot be readed using jquery ajax.even 
 i am trying  the  same  using  $.getjson().The output cannot be loaded.

please help me.

This is My Plunker

https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview

Comment: it is an empty plunker

Comment: you mention "local json file". are you trying to read from a file on the user's local disk? That's not possible.

Comment: I think you should look into this @GOPAL http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one link as below to guide you :

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

And there is another way also to do the same :
It uses uses FileReader and JSON.parser (and no jquery).

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function loadFile() {
    var input, file, fr;

    if (typeof window.FileReader !== 'function') {
      alert("The file API isn't supported on this browser yet.");
      return;
    }

    input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
    if (!input) {
      alert("Um, couldn't find the fileinput element.");
    }
    else if (!input.files) {
      alert("This browser doesn't seem to support the `files` property of file inputs.");
    }
    else if (!input.files[0]) {
      alert("Please select a file before clicking 'Load'");
    }
    else {
      file = input.files[0];
      fr = new FileReader();
      fr.onload = receivedText;
      fr.readAsText(file);
    }

    function receivedText(e) {
      lines = e.target.result;
      var newArr = JSON.parse(lines); 
    }
  }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

More ever getJson also should work, Are you parsing json object after using getJson?

Comment: Too complicated stuff for a simple solution